# Coxph predictions don't match the coefficients

Tags: r, predict, survival-analysis, cox-regression, cox

Good afternoon,

I could post reproducible code and certainly will if everyone agrees that something is wrong, but right now I think my question is quite simple and someone will point me the right path.

I am working in a data set like this:

```
created_as_free_user     t     c
                 <fctr> <int> <int>
1                  true    36     0
2                  true    36     0
3                  true     0     1
4                  true    28     0
5                  true     9     0
6                  true     0     1
7                  true    13     0
8                  true    19     0
9                  true     9     0
10                 true    16     0
```

I fitted a Cox Regression model like this:

```
fit_train = coxph(Surv(time = t,event = c) ~ created_as_free_user ,data = teste)
summary(fit_train)
```

And received:

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time = t, event = c) ~ created_as_free_user, 
    data = teste)

  n= 9000, number of events= 1233 

                            coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
created_as_free_usertrue -0.7205    0.4865   0.1628 -4.426 9.59e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

                         exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
created_as_free_usertrue    0.4865      2.055    0.3536    0.6693

Concordance= 0.511  (se = 0.002 )
Rsquare= 0.002   (max possible= 0.908 )
Likelihood ratio test= 15.81  on 1 df,   p=7e-05
Wald test            = 19.59  on 1 df,   p=9.589e-06
Score (logrank) test = 20.45  on 1 df,   p=6.109e-06
```

So far so good.
Next step: Predict the results on new data.
I understand the different types of predictions that predict.coxph can give me (or at least I think I do). Let's use the type = "lp":

```
head(predict(fit_train,validacao,type = "lp"),n=20)
```

And get:

```
     1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10 
-0.01208854 -0.01208854 -0.01208854 -0.01208854 -0.01208854 -0.01208854 -0.01208854 -0.01208854 -0.01208854 -0.01208854 
         11          12          13          14          15          16          17          18          19          20 
-0.01208854 -0.01208854  0.70842049 -0.01208854 -0.01208854 -0.01208854 -0.01208854 -0.01208854 -0.01208854 -0.01208854
```

OK. But when I look at the data that I am trying to estimate:

```
# A tibble: 9,000 × 3
   created_as_free_user     t     c
                 <fctr> <int> <int>
1                  true    20     0
2                  true    12     0
3                  true     0     1
4                  true    10     0
5                  true    51     0
6                  true    36     0
7                  true    44     0
8                  true     0     1
9                  true    27     0
10                 true     6     0
# ... with 8,990 more rows
```

It makes me confuse....

The type = "lp" isn't suppose to give you the linear predictions? 
For this data above that I am trying to estimate, since the created_as_free_user     variable is equal to true, Am I wrong expecting the type = "lp" prediction to be exactaly -0.7205 (the coefficient of the model above)? Where does the -0.01208854 came? I suspect it's some sort of scale situation, but couldn't find the answer online.

My final objective is the h(t) that is given by the prediction type = "expected", but I am not all that comfortable using it because it uses this -0.01208854 value that I don't fully understand.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Details section in `?predict.coxph` reads:

> The Cox model is a *relative* risk model; predictions of type
>        "linear predictor", "risk", and "terms" are all relative to the
>        sample from which they came.  By default, the reference value for
>        each of these is the mean covariate within strata.

To illustrate what this means, we can look at a simple example. Some fake data:

```
test1 <- list(time=c(4,3,1,1,1), 
             status=c(1,1,1,0,0), 
             x=c(0,2,1,1,0))
```

We fit a model and view predictions:

```
fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ x, test1) 
predict(fit, type = "lp")
# [1] -0.6976630  1.0464945  0.1744157  0.1744157 -0.6976630
```

The predictions are the same as:

```
(test1$x - mean(test1$x)) * coef(fit)
# [1] -0.6976630  1.0464945  0.1744157  0.1744157 -0.6976630
```

(Using this logic and some arithmetic we can back out from your results that you have 8849 "trues" out of 9000 observations for your `created_as_free_user` variable.)