# Linear predictor from coefficients of Cox PH model

Tags: r, validation, survival-analysis, calibration, cox-regression

I need to calculate the linear predictor of a Cox PH model by hand.

I can get continuous and binary variables to match the output of predict.coxph (specifying 'lp') but I can't seem to figure out how to calculate it for categorical variables with more than 2 levels.

My aim is to assess calibration of a published model in my own data-I only have coefficients so need to be able to do this by hand.

This previous post describes how to calculate for continuous variables...

([Coxph predictions don't match the coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843239/coxph-predictions-dont-match-the-coefficients))

Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Since this doesn't seem like a programming task, Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask such a question. If you want to calculate statistics by hand, instead you should consult with the statisticians over at [stats.se] for help.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to the site...I've posted on cross validate and re-posted here with programming example-thanks!