# R : does `predict` still center linear predictors of categorical variables?

Tags: r, prediction, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

Until then, to obtain the linear predictors of a Cox model via  `predict`, it was accepted that the linear predictors were centred.
When they were recalculated, the **continuous and categorical** variables were centered (see [Linear predictor from predict.coxph from coefficients only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630381/linear-predictor-from-predict-coxph-from-coefficients-only) and [Coxph predictions don't match the coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843239/coxph-predictions-dont-match-the-coefficients)).

But when I test this now it appears that **only continuous variables are centered**. To reuse the link example:

```
URL   <- "http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/data/Rossi.txt"
Rossi <- read.table(URL, header=TRUE)                  
library(survival)     

#for binary variable
fitCPH <- coxph(Surv(week, arrest) ~ fin, data=Rossi)    #Cox-PH model
(coefCPH <- coef(fitCPH))                              # estimated coefficients
head(predict(fitCPH,type="lp"))
head((as.numeric(as.factor((Rossi$fin))) - 1) - mean(as.numeric(as.factor(Rossi$fin)) - 1)    * coef(fitCPH)) #centered
head((as.numeric(as.factor((Rossi$fin))) - 1)    * coef(fitCPH)) #non-centered
```

**Can someone confirm the information and the reason for this change?**

Comment: When I run the data and code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843239/coxph-predictions-dont-match-the-coefficients   .... I get exactly the same results. The linear predictor is not "predicting" survival time or survival fraction, rather it is predicting log relative hazard. In the case of categorical variable it has always been a treatment contrast by default so the log relative hazard would based on the reference factor level.

Comment: As I said in my post, continuous variable are still centered. I was taking about categorical variables.

Comment: As I said in my comment the reference level for factor variable has always been the base level. You have not offered any evidence that this was different in the past than the current situation. There no centering of factor coefficients and there  never has been at least for the default choice of contrasts. You may be confusing the base hazard estimates.

Comment: @IRTFM : In the link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630381/linear-predictor-from-predict-coxph-from-coefficients-only it seemed that the linear predictors were centered for the categorical variables. In any case, I don't get the same results as those displayed in the example. What do you think? `
fitCPH <- coxph(Surv(week, arrest) ~ fin, data=Rossi)    #Cox-PH model
head(predict(fitCPH,type="lp")) #[1]  0.1845346  0.1845346  0.1845346 -0.1845346  0.1845346  0.1845346`

Comment: I get: `[1]  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.3690692  0.0000000  0.0000000`

Comment: Maybe you have changed the default contrasts? What do you get for `options("contrasts")`? I get `$contrasts
        unordered           ordered 
"contr.treatment"      "contr.poly"`. As I said before, the default for the most commonly used type of factor is to used "treatment contrasts". ( And I thin both you and the referenced earlier question had `options` set to something other than treatment contrasts. Furthermore yours are the same as earlier example.)

Comment: What you got is not what the post author got in his post: he had `#[1] 0.1845346 0.1845346 0.1845346 -0.1845346 0.1845346 0.1845346` and you get `[1]  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.3690692  0.0000000  0.0000000`. That's why I thought that things had changed

Comment: I understand. Do you get the same results as I do when your contrasts are the same? (Many times people trying to replicate results from SAS or SPSS will fiddle with the contrast specification to replicate findings obtained in another system that has different defaults.)

Comment: With `options("contrasts")`I get the same thing than you `$contrasts   unordered          ordered "contr.treatment"      "contr.poly" ` :-)

Comment: If we’re intending to make a report of anomalous behavior, we would both need to present output of sessionInfo()